# Painting ComboBox DropDown arrow on DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, datagridview, custom-controls

What I want is when the mouse moves over a DataGridViewCell, I want to identify the cell under the mouse, and draw a ComboBox DownArrow on it.  When the mouse moves off the cell, I want just the "normal" cell to be drawn.

I figured that I need to paint the cell under the mouse, **and** repaint the cell that it was previously under, to clear any previous custom-drawn arrow.

The way I do this is as follows **NOTE: All this code is at the DataGridView level, not the cell level.**

```
private DataGridViewCell LastCell;
private DataGridViewCell MouseCell;
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);

    DataGridViewCell currentCell = GetCellUnderCursor();
    if (currentCell != MouseCell)   //Has moved to a new cell
    {
        LastCell = MouseCell;
        MouseCell = currentCell;
        if (currentCell != null) this.InvalidateCell(currentCell);
        if (LastCell != null) this.InvalidateCell(LastCell);
    }
    else
    {
        //Has not changed cell - don't paint again - exit to prevent flicker
        return;
    }
}
```

I have tested this, and it works well to paint the cell with the mouse under it, and clear the other cells.

The "Test" was done using this code to simply draw a rectangle around the cell.

```
protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    //call base method
    base.OnCellPainting(e);
    e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex == -1) return;

    //Is the mouse over this cell?
    DataGridViewCell cell = GetCellUnderCursor();
    if (cell == null) return; //row or column is -1

    DataGridViewCell paintingCell = this.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (paintingCell != cell) return;


    //Paint the cell, excluding the border.
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);

    //Now paint a custom border.
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.RoyalBlue, 1))
    {
        Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
        rect.Width -= 2;
        rect.Height -= 2;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
    }
    e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

As stated, this all works well - I get a nice blue rectangle following my mouse around the DataGridView.

I then tried to develop similar code to draw a ComboBox Dropdown arrow, and am trying to do it with the ComboBoxRenderer class:

```
Size arrowSize = new Size(18,20);
Rectangle arrowRectangle = new Rectangle(e.ClipBounds.X + e.ClipBounds.Width - arrowSize.Width -1, e.ClipBounds.Y+1,arrowSize.Width, arrowSize.Height);
Rectangle topTextBoxRectangle = new Rectangle(e.ClipBounds.X, e.ClipBounds.Y, e.ClipBounds.Width, arrowSize.Height+2);
ComboBoxState arrowState = ComboBoxState.Normal;
if (!ComboBoxRenderer.IsSupported)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Renderer not supported");
    return;
}
else
{
    string cellText = cell.Value == null ? "" : cell.Value.ToString();
    ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(e.Graphics, arrowRectangle, arrowState);
    //ComboBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(e.Graphics, topTextBoxRectangle, cellText, this.Font, ComboBoxState.Normal);
    e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
}
e.Handled = true;
```

This really doesn't work well at all - painting of the cells *sometimes* paints the dropdown (seems to paint it on the wrong cell - the cell above?)  If you are moving the mouse down the DataGridView, it paints the cell above.  If you are moving it up, it paints the correct cell (really!), and moving down doesn't clear any old drawings, but moving up does.  Similarly, moving the mouse left-to-right gives the correct behavior, but not right to left.

I found that `e.PaintContents(e.ClipBounds)` appears to work much better than `ComboBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox()`

Note that this code is used at the "Paint the cell" part of the above code.

Any suggestions to fix this, or what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - problem solved!

I was setting the drawing to:

```
Rectangle arrowRectangle = new Rectangle(e.ClipBounds.X + e.ClipBounds.Width - arrowSize.Width -1, 
    e.ClipBounds.Y+1,arrowSize.Width, arrowSize.Height);
```

When it should have been using CellBounds, not ClipBounds:

```
Rectangle arrowRectangle = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + e.CellBounds.Width - arrowSize.Width - 1, 
    e.CellBounds.Y + 1, arrowSize.Width, arrowSize.Height);
```